# eclipse importing a mavenproject

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

Please please help me ,

I have eclipse Luna installed (which is preloaded with maven), installed Maven Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
C:\>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T17:29:2
3+00:00)
Maven home: C:\software\apache-maven-3.2.5-bin\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

I have imported a maven project 
    Eclipse keeps giving me `ERROR:Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE`.

There is about 61 of these errors. How do I clear these ??

I am new to Maven , I found some example code which I am trying to import.

Thanks in advance 
Jemrug

Comment: In eclipse menu "maven" use update Project and the error should gone.

Comment: Try doing a maven update by right clicking on the project and going under maven

Comment: Update your questione addio the pomeriggio definition. This will help us to figure out what is the problem

Comment: Complete error message would also be helpful. Have you checked if the build is working on command line first?

Comment: Guys thank you so much .. the "maven" use update project was perfect solution.

Comment: Guys I'm new to importing a maven project.  Most of my errors are now cured apart from the following:- `cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'cloud:data-source'.`  **   cloud datasource ** Multiple annotations found at this line: - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring/cloudfoundry- spring-0.8.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>. - .**  What do I do to correct this?